# CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project but they are set to NOTFOUND

Tags: cmake, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

Actually, I am working on Ubuntu 14 and Indigo Version, so am trying to make some packages. I got an error message below :

```
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
Modbus_LIBRARIES
   linked by target "<package_name>" in directory /home/tayssir/catkin_ws/src/robot_ws_debug/src/package_name

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/tayssir/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/tayssir/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

I tried to use **ROS_LANG_DISABLE**  like is mentioned in [ROS EnvironmentVariables](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_LANG_DISABLE) :

$export ROS_LANG_DISABLE=genlisp

but this can not solve the problem.

How would I fix it? Thanks.

---

Edit: Thanks for your help @gvdhoorn, and I'm going through the tutorial [modbus](http://wiki.ros.org/modbus) to install it, and there is my CMAKE File below :

```
find_path(Modbus_INCLUDE_DIR modbus/modbus.h
   HINTS
   /usr/include/modbus
   /usr/local/include
   )

find_library(Modbus_LIBRARIES NAMES modbus
   HINTS
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
   /usr/local/lib
   )

include_directories(
   ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
   ${Modbus_INCLUDE_DIR}/modbus
   )
```

It seems that my environment is set correctly! But I don’t know where is the problem and how can I resolve it??!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/322898/cmake-error:-the-following-variables-are-used-in-this-project-but-they-are-set-to-notfound./) by [Tayssir Boubaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/40137/tayssir-boubaker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2019-05-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the error message, I don't believe this has anything to do with `ROS_LANG_DISABLE`.

> ```
> Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files: Modbus_LIBRARIES
> ```

it would appear that *some* package in your workspace needs Modbus functionality and the `CMakeLists.txt` is probably using something like `find_package(..)` or `find_library(..)` and fails. Those then set `Modbus_LIBRARIES` to `NOTFOUND`, leading to CMake printing the error that you show.

You'll have to check what uses Modbus in your workspace and resolve any problem it has finding the required libraries.

---

Edit:

> I'm going through the tutorial [modbus](http://wiki.ros.org/modbus) to install it

Judging from the `CMakeLists.txt` you show, I doubt the `modbus` package you link to is the one that your package is looking for, for two reasons:

1. that package is a Python package (so does not provide any C++ libraries)
2. your `CMakeLists.txt` uses `find_library(..)` and `find_path(..)`, instead of `find_package(..)`

You'll have to figure out which particular library/package/project your package requires, otherwise this will be difficult to fix.

Is there any information in a readme perhaps, or some other form of documentation? Does the `package.xml` of your package tell you anything?

> but I'm an absolute beginner with ROS

please note: this is not actually a ROS problem (any more), but a general "how do I make sure all dependencies of my software are installed" and CMake problem. When looking for help, you don't need to limit yourself to ROS fora.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tayssir Boubaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/40137/tayssir-boubaker/) on 2019-05-11**:
thanks for your help , but the project that am working on ,have not any documentation so the only thing that i should find a solution with my CMAKE files

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-11**:
Then you will have to figure out which particular version of or library `modbus` actually is.

Does the `package.xml` give any clues?

A quick google suggests it *could perhaps* be [stephane/libmodbus](https://github.com/stephane/libmodbus). But that is just a guess.

**Comment by [Tayssir Boubaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/40137/tayssir-boubaker/) on 2019-05-11**:
thank you very much, your suggestions helped me to solve the problem .. when am looking for the `modbus` version .. I discover that the library was not installed and can not find any commands !! So a simple update and install .. solve the problem :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libmodbus-dev
```